# InsertOnSubmit on Linq - Put it into the database

Tags: c#, linq

This is how I am going to do so that the users of the website can sustain themselves, but when I try to do like this,

What I could'm going to happened in the code here was to create the user in the database.

```
protected void ButtonOpretbruger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fejl = "Hov Hov, Du skal læse vore betingelser";

    if (CheckBoxBetingelser.Checked)
    {
        LabelError.Visible = false;
        string brugernavn = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxBrugernavn.Text);

        //checks if username exists in the database.
        var opretbrugerTjekEMail = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(brugerEmail => brugerEmail.brugernavn == brugernavn);
        if (opretbrugerTjekEMail == null)
        {
            //Begin to create user in the database.
            opretbrugerTjekEMail.brugernavn = brugernavn;
            opretbrugerTjekEMail.adgangskode = Hash.getHashSha256(TextBoxAdgangskode.Text);
            opretbrugerTjekEMail.fornavn = TextBoxFornavn.Text;
            opretbrugerTjekEMail.efternavn = TextBoxEfternavn.Text;

            db.brugeres.InsertOnSubmit(opretbrugerTjekEMail);

            db.SubmitChanges();

            //send users to login site.
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            LabelErrorBesked.Text = "Hov hov, denne her email er optaget " + brugernavn;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error her
        LabelError.Text = fejl;
    }
}
```

The error I receive looks like this,

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Dont't you think  you should check for not null here?  `if (opretbrugerTjekEMail == null){ opretbrugerTjekEMail.brugernavn = brugernavn;`

Comment: `opretbrugerTjekEMail = new brugeres()`

Comment: i will look on its @RahulSingh

Comment: What do you think I should do? @RahulSingh

Comment: Where do you want it? @entropic

Comment: The first statement after `if (opretbrugerTjekEMail == null)` evaluates to true.

Comment: @JesperPetersen - It's pretty obvious, you are getting null in `opretbrugerTjekEMail ` and you are assigning properties to null, change it to `(opretbrugerTjekEMail != null)` to avoid this exception. Then debug your code and see why its null, why this condition `brugerEmail.brugernavn == brugernavn` is not returning any result.

Comment: error come and say `The type or namespace name 'brugeres' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` @entropic

Comment: @RahulSingh so you would rather have it down if? `If(brugerEmail.brugernavn == brugernavn)`

Comment: What is the name of the class you are using? Is it Brugere, Brugeres, Bruger?  What's happening is you haven't instantiated the object yet.  The link in the first comment is literally the problem you are having.

Comment: @entropic `brugeres` is the name of my use as I have in the database.